# Node.js: Archive the output of a git clone operation

Tags: node.js, github

I want to write a utility in Node.js which when executed, fetches the latest code from a bitbucket/GitHub repository with the supplied user credentials and stores the repository to a tar.gz archive instead of cloning it to a folder. I am thinking of using the `child_process` module to run the `git clone` command. However, not sure how to go about archiving the output as a stream. One way to go about it would be to add a listener to the "end" event of the child process and then use some archive module to store all the files in the directory by the name of the repo to an archive. Is there any way this could be done while streaming the data from Bitbucket ?

Comment: I have built something like this before. Long story short, try to use child process as much as possible. I ran into a bunch of problems running the same git app on OSX and a Linux server. If you want look into it, I also leveraged this https://www.npmjs.com/package/simple-git

Comment: [Archiver](http://archiverjs.com/docs/) can take input as a stream, so if you can redirect your `git clone` output as a stream you might be able to pipe it in.